# Yes/No toogle switch in cshtml

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to add a yes/no toggle switch in cshtml and I was wondering how to do this currently I have tried this:

```
    <td class="slider-td">
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input name="DelegateChkBox" id="IsEnabled" type="checkbox" value="true" data-val-required="The IsEnabled field is required." data-val="true" data-bind="checked: IsEnabled">
                        <div class="slider round"></div>
                    </label>
                </td>
```

However it is only displaying a checkbox. How would I add a toggle switch instead?

Comment: A toggle switch is not an HTML element -- it's styling.  Can you please edit your question and add the css segment that pertains to your HTML checkbox?  We need to see the attempt at styling.

Comment: @anon: You can use [@Html.CheckBox()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkbox?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) or  [@Html.RadioButton()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobutton?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) depend on what type of the control you need (one checkbox or two radio buttons).